# Checker the output sequence is correct or not

Tags: c++, c, file, io

I am doing a homework , and have to check the result , but the problem is I dont know what i need to fill up .
What is the checker mean? if the input.txt ( inFile) is I 23 I 1 R 3 R 4 and the output.txt ( outFile) is 23 0 0 0

```
#include<cstdio>

//Check whether the output sequence is correct or not.
//If it is correct, return true. Otherwise, return false.
bool Checker(FILE* inFile, FILE* outFile)
{
    //TODO
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
    FILE* outFile = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    printf("%s\n", Checker(inFile, outFile)?"YES":"NO");

    fclose(outFile);
    fclose(inFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just about the only C++ here is `cstdio`, not sure the C++ tag is warranted.

Comment: For this first you have understand what is the output sequence expected for an input sequence. are you trying to check if the input and out files are same or not?

Answer (score 0):

Read both files into memory, and compare the memory.

Read about e.g. [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), [`fseek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek), [`ftell`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell), [`rewind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind), [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp).